# Mule 4 : Getting error while reading CSV file, Malformed Input

Tags: mule, mule4

I am reading a CSV file using File READ operation in Mule 4.
One of the CSV columns has double quotes in its values.
While reading the CSv file I am getting the error :

```
Malformed CSV input. Ignoring following chars after quoted value at offset 45270921: "A"" BLING KEY RING"
```

I tried by adding reader property **quote** with following values  : """ , " "

Still the error exists, Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the escape reader property to a quote. Reader properties must be set at the source of the payload.

Example:

```
<file:listener doc:name="On New or Updated File" config-ref="file_config1" outputMimeType='application/csv; escape="\""' directory="/some/path/to/file" recursive="false" >
```

Comment: Have the same issue calling the Salesforce BULK API to get query results (the connector performance is not good / known issue)...  :(